# Cleanest way to implement multiple email system in django?

Tags: django, email

Hey everyone, I am pretty sure this is a fairly common problem.
So in order to register an account my site you need an email address from certain school domain (like facebook). This wouldn't be that big a problem until you start integrating other apps, like django-notification and django-registration and django-socialregistration into your site where they are sending email via user.email.

I have asked my users and most of them want an 'active_email' option - that means that they can change the email to their designated gmail or whatever.

I have come up with the following solution which isn't the cleanest of all: 
First, I inherit from User in django.contrib.auth and call this new class MultipleEmailUser, with email=active_email and official_email=sch_email.

Then I override django.contrib.auth's UserManager to change the API slightly,
And the most painful part is to change all the source code that has User.object.find() to MultipleEmailUser.find().

Can someone suggest me a cleaner way? (My biggest headache arise from other apps only permitting to send email to User.email.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need - or want - to modify the User class. Just set up a UserProfile class with a OneToOneField back to User, and set the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#auth-profiles).

Comment: Having researched this further, I believe you're entirely correct.  Django purists will definitely want to take heed of this advice, and ignore mine!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a true datastore attribute, you could use a `property` called 'email' to expose access to whatever data you want.

Basic property syntax (from the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)):

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def getx(self):
        return self._x
    def setx(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def delx(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(getx, setx, delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
```

In your case, you could create true datastore attributes named, for instance, `auth_email` and `active_email`.  Then, the User.email property could perform some logic in its getter function, to determine which one to return (i.e. **if `active_email` is set, return it; otherwise, return `auth_email`**)

It's worth noting that the syntax for `property` has undergone some flux.  As of python 2.7, it can be implemented in a more readable way, as a decorator:

```
class User(BaseModel):
  @property # email
  def email(self):
    if self.active_email:
      return self.active_email
    return self.auth_email
```

Comment: Well if i do so how should I go about approaching this? Should I subclass User to another class (i.e. MultipleEmailUser), and implement this property? Doesn't that lead me back to square one where I have to go to all my plugins and change User to MultipleEmailUser?

Comment: It won't lead you to square one, because presumably all of your plugins access the user through `user.email`, which in my above code would run a function.  A python 'property' is essentially an attribute whose get/set/delete operations run through custom code, which you can customize to your liking.